# Can we use a variable containing linux command result in the python code

Tags: python, bash

I am working with shell scripting and trying to learn Python scripting, any suggestion is welcome.

I want to achieve something like below:

Usage1:

```
ps_result=`ps -eaf|grep -v "grep" | grep "programmanager"`
```

then can we straight away use `ps_result` variable in python code; if yes, how?

Usage2:

```
matched_line=`cat file_name |grep "some string"`
```

can we use `matched_line` variable in python code as a list, if yes how?

PS: If possible assume I am writing the bash and python code in the one file, if not possible request you to please suggest a way. TIA

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run is a common way to run programs in python.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it via **environment variables**.

First, define the environment variable for the shell using `export`:

```
$ export ps_result=`ps -eaf|grep -v "grep" | grep "programmanager"`
```

Then, import the `os` module in Python and read the environment variable:

```
$ python -c 'import os; ps_result=os.environ.get("ps_result"); print(ps_result)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Second question first, if you run `python -`, python will run the script piped on stdin. There are several functions in python `subprocess` that let you run other programs. So you could write

test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

python - << endofprogram
import subprocess as subp

result = subp.run('ps -eaf | grep -v "grep" | grep "python"',
    shell=True, capture_output=True)
if result.returncode == 0:
    matched_lines = result.stdout.decode().split("\n")
    print(matched_lines)
endofprogram
```

In this example we pipe via the shell but python can chain stdout/stdin also, albeit more verbosely.